# TRIRIGA Installation error - the installer cannot determine the status of WebSphere

Tags: websphere, websphere-traditional

During Tririga installation over WebSphere, in the step of WebSphere configuration, then next, it will try to connect to WebSphere using serverStatus.bat but the result is:

" WebSphere Server Status

The installer cannot determine the status of WebSphere, or WebSphere is not in the STARTED state.
WebSphere should be started at this point, please click back and try again once WebSphere has started.
If WebSphere is started, please make sure the username and password are correct.
The command that was run to determine was:
[-WebSphere path-\serverStatus.bat, SERVERNAME, -username, admin, -password, password, -profileName, TRIRIGA]  "

1. WebSphere is started, I am able to login and browse the UI.
2. User name and password are correct, as I am copying and pasting them on the Tririga installation Wizard.
3. If a run this command from cmd, I get no output nor error message.

Please advise :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that, I was copying the password from Excel (copying the entire cell instead of the cell content), and my theory is that clipboard had a carriage return and the installer took that character and thus password validation was failing.